# Order columns of DataFrame according to values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following input:

```
col1    col2    col3
1       4       0
0       12      2
2       12      4
3       2       1
```

I want to sort the DataFrame according to the values in the columns, e.g. sorting it primarily for `df[df==0].count()` and secondarily for `df.sum()` would produce the output:

```
col2    col3    col1
4       0       1
12      2       0
12      4       2
2       1       3
```

`pd.DataFrame.sort()` takes a colum object as argument, which does not apply here, so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I think your zero count is increasing from right to left whereas your sum is decreasing, so I think you need to clarify that. You can get the number of zero rows simply by `(df == 0).sum()`.

To sort by a single aggregate, you can do something like:

```
col_order = (df == 0).sum().sort(inplace=False).index
df[col_order]
```

This sorts the series of aggregates by its values and the resulting index is the columns of `df` in the order you want. 
To sort on two sets of values would be more awkward/tricky but you could do something like

```
aggs = pd.DataFrame({'zero_count': (df == 0).sum(), 'sum': df.sum()})
col_order = aggs.sort(['zero_count', 'sum'], inplace=False).index
df[col_order]
```

Note that the `sort` method takes an `ascending` parameter which takes either a Boolean or a list of Booleans of equal length to the number of columns you are sorting on, e.g.

```
df.sort(['a', 'b', ascending=[True, False])
```

Comment: Thanks, ok should have clarified that. As you pointed out, I want little zero count and high sum. Btw, what's the difference between `(df == 0).sum()`  and `df[df==0].count()` ? Your way doesn't seem much simpler.

Comment: Ah there's nothin it really. You just have the comparison and the method call rather than the comparison, boolean indexing and then the method call. You can safely ignore that part : )